# fetch the row whose id is maximum with respect to other foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `Car` and `Rent`

```
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| pk_carid | fk_rentid | name    | status |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 1        | 1         | toyota  | gone   |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 2        | 2         | tata    | here   |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 3        | 3         | ferrri  | here   |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 4        | 1         | toyota  | here   |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 5        | 2         | tata    | gone   |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 6        | 3         | ferrrii | gone   |
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

---

I want to just fetch record where `pk_cardid` is 4, 5, or 6 but not 1, 2, or 3.

I have tried following query but it is giving me a record of just the last row where `pk_carid = 6`.

---

```
SELECT c.cardid
       ,r.rentid
       ,c.name, 
FROM cars AS c 
     INNER JOIN rent AS r 
     ON r.rentid = c.carid
WHERE (c.carid =(SELECT MAX(c2.carid) Expr1 FROM cars c2 )) group by r.rentid
```

Comment: So basically you want to show the cars that are not rented?

Comment: @RaulCuth no actually just there latest status weather they re rented or not and we know we can get this by checking latest primary keys of respective foreign keys

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are wanting given this sample data. Can you also share an example (based on this sample data) of your desired results?

Comment: " i want to just fetch record of pk_cardid 4, 5 ,6". Why those results? What is it about those rows which means they should be returned? It isn't clear, from your description, why those are the required rows.

Comment: @JNevill i want to fetech the row whose pk re 4, 5 and 6 because these are latest rows of fk_rentid

Comment: @ADyson i want to fetech the row whose pk re 4, 5 and 6 because these are latest rows of fk_rentid

Comment: I don't follow you - "latest rows"...SQL tables don't have an inherent order, and the fk_rentID (this is actually a car ID, I think?? If so, it could be named better) values are repeated in your data. Show us the raw data in the rent and car tables, please. Do you have some sort of date fields which shows when the rental is/was taking place, and by which we could determine the most recent record? I am starting to suspect that maybe your data structure is inadequate, but we need to see it really.

Comment: @ADyson i want to fetch all rows of foreign keys who have greater primary keys, let i have foreign 1 and it is present in 4 rows and these 4 rows have pk 5, 6 , 7 and  and i want to just fetch row who have pk 8 not 5 ,6 and 7

Comment: This smells like a design flaw. You shouldn't be relying on arbitrary key IDs to determine this, I don't think. You want to get the latest status of the car? There should be date fields to record precisely when things happened. Then you can find its status at any time in history, should you need to. Again, show your raw data. I think this is not the correct approach to your problem.

Comment: @ADyson if i add date attribute in cars table then can i fetch the result on latest date based ? means latest after current date

Comment: Did you try my answer? I made some edits.

Comment: I think in your rent table you need a From date (when that rental status started) and an To date (when that rental status ended). For the "current" or "latest" status, the "To" date will be null, since this status is still current and not been updated yet. For all others the "To" date should be completed, and it should match the "From" date of the next status. Then you can ask the database, for any date you like, what the status of the car was/is. You can also simply ask for the current status by restricting to rows where the To date is null.

Comment: Your problem is called [groupwise maximum](http://oobrien.com/2012/05/the-mysql-groupwise-maximum-problem/) and it's probably the most frequently asked sql question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select cars.* from cars
join
(
   select max(carid) as id  
   from cars 
   group by rentid
)as maxCar on maxCar.id = cars.carid
```

or you can try

```
select * from cars
where carid in
(
   select max(carid) as id  
   from cars 
   group by rentid
)
```

Comment: it returned me 0 rows .

Comment: Is the table you posted in your question the cars table?

Comment: do you get anything back when you run just  the inner query? select max(carid) as id  
   from cars 
   group by rentid

Comment: then try the second query that I added to my answer.

Comment: sir am new and want to learn atleast basics of sql queries which will help me in web developing so any suggestion to become pro like you ?

Comment: there are some great courses on udemy.com on sql for free or for very cheap. good luck!